# Outlook in the office - restricted access - how to sync calendar with something at home?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2003, calendar

our department has very restricted access to the internet. OWA is no longer available.
In the office there are no private software installations allowed, additional software is restricted, too, e.g. it is not allowed to have google chrome or your favorite sync tool installed.

Now i have a problem: how to manage my private and my office calendar?

Does somebody know how to export or sync the Outlook 2003 calendar to be used at home e.g. with Thunderbird (Suse linux is used).

Note:
For programming purpose i have python and pywin32 installed ;-). Using office 2003 tolls is possible, too. I saw examples to create new calendar entries using python.

My PC is up over night, so i think about using a Rule to send a encrypted mail to my home address to get the list of meetings next day...

Using Google calendar or third party tools on the office machine is no appropriate solution.

Other suggestions?

Thanks for reading

Comment: would running a portable sync tool without actually installing it to the system be an viable solution?

Comment: hmm - it would be possible to do this, but it is not allowed